Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Self referencing loop detected for property 'Task' with type
I have an error coming on the post async method:
public async Task<string> FucntionAsync(string pTransactionId, int pTransactionSetId, String pSourceXMLUrl, String pXSLTUrl, string uri, TenantConfigModel Tenant,string _environment)
{
    bool throwMappingException = true;
    try
    {
        MappingHugeFilePayload mappingHugeFilePayload = new MappingHugeFilePayload();
        mappingHugeFilePayload.SourceXMLUrl = pSourceXMLUrl;
        mappingHugeFilePayload.XSLTUrl = pXSLTUrl;
        mappingHugeFilePayload.TransactionId = pTransactionId;
        mappingHugeFilePayload.TenantId = Tenant.Id;
        mappingHugeFilePayload.Environment = _environment;

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
           // ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
        };

        var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mappingHugeFilePayload, settings);
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri + "/PostHugeFile", new StringContent(serializedObject, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
        var Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data, settings);

        if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new MappingAPIException(response.ReasonPhrase);
        }

        if (Data.statuscode == 200)
        {
            string dataUrl = Convert.ToString(Data.data);
            string urlFileContainer = dataUrl.Split('/')[3];
            string relativeUrl = dataUrl.Split(new string[] { urlFileContainer + "/" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
            var readdata = await Tenant.AzureBlob.DownloadFileStringInChunks(relativeUrl, urlFileContainer, false);
            return readdata;
        }
        else
        {
            string error = Data.data;
            throwMappingException = false;
            throw new Exception(error, new Exception(error));
        }
    }
    catch (MappingAPIException exp)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (throwMappingException)
        {
            throw new MappingAPIException(ex.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            BaseErrors lObjError = null;
            lObjError = new MapperErrors();
            lObjError.ErrorId = 0;//Global.ErrorCodes.ApplicationException;
            lObjError.ErrorDescription = ex.Message;
            lObjError.TransactionId = pTransactionId;
            lObjError.TransactionSetId = pTransactionSetId;

            throw lObjError;
        }
    }
}

The error i'm getting is:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Self referencing loop detected for property 'Task' with type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Object,FunctionApp.Mapper.Mapping.MappingFunctionHelper+<MappingOutbound>d__10]'. Path 'StateMachine.<>t__builder'.'

Even though i am using the json settings explicitly but still the error is not going away.
when i remove await method to .Result for response the issue gets fixed, but it is not an optimal solution to remove async which will cause bottleneck at some point.

Are you using ASP.NET API? What's your controller code?

i cannot share the code, but this is an issue occurring in a Function app. In which i have to hit a url (an api) to get the desired output

From the error message it's most likely you forgot to await your Task in the Controller (or whatever you are returning). You are returning a Task object instead of the awaited result.

return readdata;
this is the line which shows what's returning and it has await added in the previous line. or can you be more specific where and what's missing?

are you saying HttpClient.PostAsync Method is not returning awaited result?

If you are sure that variable is a string, then it's something wrong with the caller of FucntionAsync. I don't know what is calling that method but I suspect the issue is from there.
